# If I make a file executable on one system, will it remain so if I move it to another?

Tags: permissions, files, chmod

If make a file executable with `chmod +x <file>` , will the change be still applied even if I move the file onto another system?

Would that apply even if I distributed the file to a wide number of users, such as through Sourceforge?

Comment: As long as all file systems the file passes on its way support the same permission system as `ext*`, it should be fine. That is if you move it with e.g. USB drives. If you upload it anywhere though, I think these meta-informations are also lost.

Comment: @ByteCommander This package: http://sourceforge.com/p/resolutionx was uploaded with executable permissions... which means that when downloaded, the permissions are removed? **:(**

Comment: Seems so. Maybe because of the file system the uploaded file is stored on the server, maybe because of the transfer itself (ftp maybe?), I don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Tl;dr

Both for moving and for copying it depends on the tool used to move / copy the file, and for copying also on the user's umask. However:

- **If the file is moved: usually YES**, as for a tool intended to move files to arbitrarily change the moved files' permissions makes little sense;
- **If the file is copied: usually NO**, as by convention copied files have permissions `666` minus the user's umask, which by default is `002`; no matter the permissions of the original file, in 99% of the cases a copied file will have permissions `664`;

---

> Copying a file =~ reading a file and writing it in another position =~ *creating a new file with the content of the original file*.

The permissions of a file copied / moved from / to the same filesystem or copied / moved from / to another filesystem depend:

1. On the tool copying / moving the file.
2. When copying, also on the user's umask, as copying a file =~ reading a file and writing it in another position =~ creating a new file with the content of the original file, so constraints that apply to newly created files also apply to copied files.

So it's totally up to the combination of the two. However:

- The *convention* is that a file *copied* from / to the same filesystem or from / to another filesystem will have the permissions set to `666` by the tool; the default umask is `002`, so in 99% of the cases the file will have permissions `664`;
- The *convention* is that a file *moved* from / to the same filesystem or from / to another filesystem will have the permissions set to the permissions of the original file by the tool;

Downloading a file from the internet has nothing to do with metadata, as metadata are a filesystem thing; permissions set to a file downloaded from the internet are set following the same "rules" that apply to a file copied from / to the same filesystem or from / to another filesystem, i.e. depending on the tool and on the user's umask.

---

So, when you download a file from the internet the permissions of the downloaded file are usually set to `664`:

```
% wget 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/resolutionx/ResolutionX.tar.gz?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fresolutionx%2F&ts=1446571625&use_mirror=netassist'
--2015-11-03 18:28:07--  http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/resolutionx/ResolutionX.tar.gz?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fresolutionx%2F&ts=1446571625&use_mirror=netassist
Resolving downloads.sourceforge.net (downloads.sourceforge.net)... 216.34.181.59
Connecting to downloads.sourceforge.net (downloads.sourceforge.net)|216.34.181.59|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://netassist.dl.sourceforge.net/project/resolutionx/ResolutionX.tar.gz [following]
--2015-11-03 18:28:08--  http://netassist.dl.sourceforge.net/project/resolutionx/ResolutionX.tar.gz
Resolving netassist.dl.sourceforge.net (netassist.dl.sourceforge.net)... 62.205.134.42, 2a01:d0:0:37::2
Connecting to netassist.dl.sourceforge.net (netassist.dl.sourceforge.net)|62.205.134.42|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 8280 (8,1K) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘ResolutionX.tar.gz?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fresolutionx%2F&ts=1446571625&use_mirror=netassist’

ResolutionX.tar.gz? 100%[=====================>]   8,09K  --.-KB/s   in 0,007s 

2015-11-03 18:28:22 (1,07 MB/s) - ‘ResolutionX.tar.gz?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fresolutionx%2F&ts=1446571625&use_mirror=netassist’ saved [8280/8280]

% ls -l
total 12
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 8280 set  1 11:55 ResolutionX.tar.gz?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fresolutionx%2F&ts=1446571625&use_mirror=netassist
```

However *files extracted from a tarball will have the permissions set based on Tar's specific constraints*;

If the user extracting the tarball is root or Tar is called passing the `-p`, `--preserve-permissions` or `--same-permissions` switch, the extracted files' permissions will be set to the permissions of the original files:

```
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % touch foo
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % chmod 777 foo
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % tar cf foo.tar foo
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % rm foo
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % tar xf foo.tar -p
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % ls -l
total 12
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user     0 nov  4 07:45 foo
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 10240 nov  4 07:45 foo.tar
```

If the user extracting the tarball is *not* root *and* Tar is *not* called passing the `-p`, `--preserve-permissions` or `--same-permissions` switch, the extracted files' permissions will be set to the permissions of the original files *minus the user's umask*:

```
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % tar xf foo.tar   
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % ls -l
total 12
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user     0 nov  4 07:45 foo
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 10240 nov  4 07:45 foo.tar
```

Comment: You forgot to mention that if you send a copy of a file in e-mail, the permissions are lost as well!  **:D  ;-)**