# how to make file keeps it's permissions even it got copied

Tags: permissions, apache2

I made an executable file with extension .sh on a webserver

```
root@internal-webserver:/var/www/html# chmod +x puppetconf.sh
```

But when I `wget` the file, the file is not executable any more.

```
root@master:~# wget 10.1.5.128/puppetconf.sh
```

New permissions:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   75 Feb 15 19:40 puppetconf.sh
```

Any suggestions how to make the file keeps the permissions?

Comment: I would say no: http://askubuntu.com/q/693514/380067

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pure combination of webserver + `wget` cannot do this. You'll have to try other options.

You can:

#### Provide a tar archive of the file

On the server:

```
tar cf puppetconf.sh.tar puppetconf.sh
```

On the client:

```
wget 10.1.5.128/puppetconf.sh.tar -O - | tar x
```

#### Use `scp`/`rsync` to copy the file

You will need to have SSH installed on the server for this. Either of the following commands would do:

```
scp 10.1.5.128:/var/www/html/puppetconf.sh .
rsync -aP 10.1.5.128:/var/www/html/puppetconf.sh .
```